# Print dynamic Text box value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <input type = "text" id="test"+i value="" onchange="getValue(i)">
}
```

I want to print selected text box value using jquery. I tried below code,....

```
function getValue(id)
{
   var value = $("#test"+id).val();
   alert(value);
}
```

Some how the above code is not working. 
if i tried like `var value = document.getElementById("test"+id);` then it is working.

Comment: what scenario is the `for` loop above?

Answer (score 0):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eyUZoN/2/edit)

```
var inp = ''; // String will hold all inputs

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    inp += '<input type="text" id="test'+i+'" value="" />'; // Generate 10 inputs
}

$('body').append( inp ); // All inputs to HTML

$('input[id^="test"]').on('input', function(){
    console.log( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't just drop raw HTML inside of a JavaScript loop like that. You have to set a string or create an element and append it to the DOM.
2. `"getValue(i)"` is a string. The `"i"` is not the variable `i`, it is literally a string with the letter *i*.
    If you want to concatenate strings and variables you have to do so like this:

```
var name = "Neil";    
var greeting = "Hi, my name is " + name + ", nice to meet you!";
```